# What does it mean for income bonds to have deductibility of interest paid from the company's taxable income?

Tags: bonds, income

What does it mean for income bonds to have deductibility of interest paid from the company's taxable income? And why does this deductibility cut the cost of that form of capital in half?

Comment: I'm not sure how you get to "cut the cost of that form of capital in half" unless the tax rate is 50%. Is there more context that would explain that part?

Comment: @DStanley I think the 50% referred to the personal tax rate, I got the question from the book The Intelligent Investor

Comment: I don't think the quote is referring to personal income/taxes at all, but it's hard to know without the full context.

Answer (score 1):

Interest payments are deductible expenses *for the company*, which reduces their cost of capital. For example, If they have a 5% coupon and a 20% tax rate, the *after-tax* interest that they pay is 4%.

I'm not sure how you get to "cut the cost of that form of capital in half" unless the tax rate is 50%.

Comment: Ok, so before a company receives interest they have on a bond, the interest income is taxed at corporate rates?

Comment: No, when a company _pays_ interest one the bonds it's issued, it can deduct that from its taxes. Similar to how an individual can deduct mortgage interest.

Comment: Ok so if a company has to pay $100 in interest, and it owes $1000 in taxes, it now only owes $900 in taxes? What's the benefit to the holder of the income bond vs other bonds?

Comment: I should have said it can deduct it from it's _taxable income_. So if it has $1000 in income and pays $100 in interest, it now only pays tax on $900 of income.

Comment: There's really no direct benefit to the owner of the bond - that's why I wonder what the full context is. Is the book saying that these bonds benefit the bondholders because the company can deduct the interest?